# Supervised classification using training samples from different months

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, classification, sentinel-2, date

I am performing supervised classifications of forest stands in the Delta region of Buenos Aires. For these classifications, I use a set of bands and indices derived from Sentinel-2 images for different dates. The forest stands that I am evaluating are deciduous, so their spectral signature varies depending on the month we are observing, resulting in temporal heterogeneity. This heterogeneity allows us to distinguish some species from others. For example, in September, pine "A" has a spectral behavior similar to pine "B", however, pine "B" loses its leaves faster than pine "A", so evaluating both September and March images can enhance the quality of the classification.

The code that I arrived at is the following:

```
/*_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
2.1 - COLECCIONES DE IMÁGENES (Septiembre)
b) Sentinel-2 
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________*/

var FechaInicio2 = '2019-09-01';
var FechaFin2 = '2019-10-18';

var bandasS2_invierno=['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B11'];

var datasetS2_invierno = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED') 
              .filterDate(FechaInicio2,FechaFin2)
              .filterBounds(departamento_roi)
              .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 1))
              .select(bandasS2_invierno);

var S2_media_invierno = datasetS2_invierno.median().clip(departamento_roi);

// INDICES

var ndvi_s2_sept = S2_media_invierno.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVIS2INV');

var EVI_sept = S2_media_invierno.expression ('float (2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1)))', {
    'NIR': S2_media_invierno.select ('B8'),  
    'RED': S2_media_invierno.select ('B4'),
    'BLUE': S2_media_invierno.select ('B2')}).rename('EVI_sep');

var GLI_sept = S2_media_invierno.expression ('float (((GREEN - RED) + (GREEN - BLUE)) / ((2 * GREEN) + RED + BLUE))', {
    'GREEN': S2_media_invierno.select ('B3'),  
    'RED': S2_media_invierno.select ('B4'),
    'BLUE': S2_media_invierno.select ('B2')}).rename('GLI_sep');

var GCI_sept = S2_media_invierno.expression ('float (((NIR) / (GREEN)) - 1)', {
    'NIR': S2_media_invierno.select ('B8'),  
    'GREEN': S2_media_invierno.select ('B3')}).rename('GCI_sep');

var compositeInvierno = ee.Image.cat(S2_media_invierno, ndvi_s2_sept, EVI_sept, GLI_sept, GCI_sept);
print (compositeInvierno, 'composite'); 


/*_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
2.1 - COLECCIONES DE IMÁGENES (Junio)
b) Sentinel-2 
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________*/

var FechaInicio3 = '2019-06-01';
var FechaFin3 = '2019-07-18';
var bandasS2_invierno3=['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B11'];

var datasetS2_invierno3 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED') 
              .filterDate(FechaInicio3,FechaFin3)
              .filterBounds(departamento_roi)
              .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 1))
              .select(bandasS2_invierno3);

// Convertir coleccion a imagen, reduce a promedio. Clipear por departamento
var S2_media_invierno3 = datasetS2_invierno3.median().clip(departamento_roi);

// INDICES
 
var ndvi_s2_invierno3 = S2_media_invierno3.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVIS2INV3');

var EVI_juni = S2_media_invierno3.expression ('float (2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1)))', {
    'NIR': S2_media_invierno3.select ('B8'),  
    'RED': S2_media_invierno3.select ('B4'),
    'BLUE': S2_media_invierno3.select ('B2')}).rename('EVI_jun');

var GLI_juni = S2_media_invierno3.expression ('float (((GREEN - RED) + (GREEN - BLUE)) / ((2 * GREEN) + RED + BLUE))', {
    'GREEN': S2_media_invierno3.select ('B3'),  
    'RED': S2_media_invierno3.select ('B4'),
    'BLUE': S2_media_invierno3.select ('B2')}).rename('GLI_jun');

var GCI_juni = S2_media_invierno3.expression ('float (((NIR) / (GREEN)) - 1)', {
    'NIR': S2_media_invierno3.select ('B8'),  
    'GREEN': S2_media_invierno3.select ('B3')}).rename('GCI_jun');

Var compositeInvierno3 = ee.Image.cat(S2_media_invierno3,ndvi_s2_invierno3,EVI_juni,GLI_juni,GCI_juni);
print (compositeInvierno3, 'composite'); 


/*_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
2.1 - COLECCIONES DE IMÁGENES (Marzo)
b) Sentinel-2 
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________*/

var FechaInicio4 = '2019-03-01';
var FechaFin4 = '2019-04-18';
var bandasS2_invierno4=['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B11'];

var datasetS2_invierno4 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED') 
              .filterDate(FechaInicio4,FechaFin4)
              .filterBounds(departamento_roi)
              .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 1))
              .select(bandasS2_invierno4);

var S2_media_invierno4 = datasetS2_invierno4.median().clip(departamento_roi);

//INDICES

var ndvi_s2_invierno4 = S2_media_invierno4.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVIS2INV4');

var EVI_marz = S2_media_invierno4.expression ('float (2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1)))', {
    'NIR': S2_media_invierno4.select ('B8'),  
    'RED': S2_media_invierno4.select ('B4'),
    'BLUE': S2_media_invierno4.select ('B2')}).rename('EVI_mar');

var GLI_marz = S2_media_invierno4.expression ('float (((GREEN - RED) + (GREEN - BLUE)) / ((2 * GREEN) + RED + BLUE))', {
    'GREEN': S2_media_invierno4.select ('B3'),  
    'RED': S2_media_invierno4.select ('B4'),
    'BLUE': S2_media_invierno4.select ('B2')}).rename('GLI_mar');

var GCI_marz = S2_media_invierno4.expression ('float (((NIR) / (GREEN)) - 1)', {
    'NIR': S2_media_invierno4.select ('B8'),  
    'GREEN': S2_media_invierno4.select ('B3')}).rename('GCI_mar');


var compositeInvierno4 = ee.Image.cat(S2_media_invierno4,ndvi_s2_invierno4,EVI_marz,GLI_marz,GCI_marz);
print (compositeInvierno4, 'composite'); 
/*_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Clasificación
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________*/

var newfc = s_babilonica.merge(s_matsudana).merge(deltoides).merge(s_nigra).merge(natural).merge(agricola).merge(agua).merge(Euca);

var opt_sar = ee.Image.cat(compositeInvierno, compositeInvierno3, compositeInvierno4, SARVV_filtered,SARVH_filtered);

var bands_opt_sar = ['VH','VV','B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7','EVI_sep','GLI_sep','GCI_sep','NDVIS2','EVI_jun','GLI_jun','GCI_jun','NDVIS2INV','EVI_mar','GLI_mar','GCI_mar','NDVIS2INV3'];

var training_opt_sar = opt_sar.select(bands_opt_sar).sampleRegions({
                collection: newfc,
                properties: ['landcover'],
                scale: 30 });

//Train the classifier
var classifier_opt_sar = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(300).train({
                features: training_opt_sar, 
                classProperty: 'landcover',
                inputProperties: bands_opt_sar 
                });

//Run the Classification
var classifiedboth = opt_sar.select(bands_opt_sar).classify(classifier_opt_sar)/*.focal_mode(1.5)*/;
```

It feels like it's not taking all the indices and all the dates into account for the classification, as if I remove some of these parameters as a test, the classification result remains similar.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You normally evaluate a supervised classification with some kind of confusion matrix, most typically with a holdout dataset.

There's an example of how to do that here:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-classify